# This Error Occur in Angular Project After Update To Version13

Tags: angular

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'Pass in my Pc'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
- install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

adding "querystring": false solved the compilation error,but then when I load http://localhost:4200 host I see an empty html page.

to properly solve the problem, run the below commands:

```
npm install webpack-dev-server@latest --save-dev
npm install querystring@latest --save
```

Thanks to the Newton Karanu on [ng new MyAngularApp fails with WebPack querystring issue, how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77126272/ng-new-myangularapp-fails-with-webpack-querystring-issue-how-to-fix)

Answer (score -1):

querystring is deprecated since at least since last Node LTS version 14.
With Angular, you can put `"querystring": false` into package.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "browser": {
    "querystring": false
  }
}
```