# ng new MyAngularApp fails with WebPack querystring issue, how to fix?

Tags: angular

I run *ng new AngularStarter*

I swap to the newly created AngularStarter directory

I run *ng serve*

It builds and then ends with:

```
*chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 60.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 9.71 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.06 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2023-09-18T09:54:43.369Z - Hash: 9da10b3c17cc9b21159c - Time: 6065ms
ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'C:\Source Code\Angulars\AngularStarter\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\utils'
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4044, open your browser on http://localhost:4044/ **
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'*
```

I guess the issue is:

```
*ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'C:\Source Code\Angulars\AngularStarter\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\utils'*
```

I can get around this by adding:

```
*"browser": {
    "querystring": false
  }*
```

to my package.json file, but then when I browse to http://localhost:4044 host I see an empty html page, no default angular app.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your project's `package.json` file, you mentioned that you added `"browser": { "querystring": false }`. While this may resolve the 'querystring' module issue, it's a workaround and not the best approach.

To properly resolve the 'querystring' issue, you should ensure that your project's dependencies are up to date. Run the following commands in your project directory:

```bash
npm install webpack-dev-server@latest --save-dev
npm install querystring@latest --save
```

These commands will update your `webpack-dev-server` and `querystring` dependencies to the latest versions, which should resolve the issue without needing to disable 'querystring' explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I did only step 1, to update  to latest webpack-dev-server and querystring  and it then built fine and now I see the default Angular app. Thanks.